# Getting LINQ query result into a list?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I'm converting old code to use LINQ.  The old code looked like this:

```
// Get Courses
sqlQuery = @"SELECT Comment.Comment, Status.StatusId, Comment.DiscussionBoardId, DiscussionBoard.CourseId, Comment.CommentID
            FROM Status INNER JOIN Comment ON Status.StatusId = Comment.StatusId INNER JOIN
                DiscussionBoard ON Comment.DiscussionBoardId = DiscussionBoard.DiscussionBoardId
            WHERE  (DiscussionBoard.CourseID = 'CourseID')";

var comments = new List<Comment>(dataContext.ExecuteQuery<Comment>(sqlQuery));
```

I've converted the above SQL to LINQ:

```
var db = new CMSDataContext();
var query = from c in db.Comments
                join s in db.Status on c.StatusId equals s.StatusId
                join d in db.DiscussionBoards on c.DiscussionBoardId equals d.DiscussionBoardId
                where d.CourseId == "CourseID"
                select new      
                {
                    d.ItemType,
                    c.Comment1,
                    s.Status1,
                    c.DiscussionBoardId,
                    d.CourseId,
                    c.CommentID
                };
```

The problem I've having, though, is with trying to get the results of the query into the List.  Can someone offer me some pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the whole query in parentheses and add `.ToList()` at the end.

Or add another line:

```
var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly!  I had no idea about the ToList method (I'm just now learning LINQ).  Thanks so much! As soon as timer is up, I'll mark answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `ToList()` method at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

How about the ToList method: `query.ToList()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do two things.

First, change your `select` to create a new instance of `Comment` instead of an anonymous type.

Second, either wrap the whole query in a call to `ToList()` or store the results in a temporary variable and call `ToList()` on that variable to get the `List<Comment>` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Either (A) wrap the entire call with `Enumerable.ToList(<your query>)`, (B) surround the entire query with parentheses and call the `ToList` extension method at the end, or (C) call `query.ToList()` as a separate statement.